# use work laptop at home

Tags: domain, workgroup

I use work laptop at home and it always connects to the work domain abc.xyz.com even at home. since I access personal stuff and open some websites which are not allowed at work like facebook, twitter, .. etc, I have some questions:

1. Does this mean that my internet traffic can be monitored by the work's network administrator even when I am connected to the home network?!
2. The laptop takes so long to boot, is there a way to prevent it from connecting this domain at home, then reconnect to the domain at work without an administrative password?
3. Sometimes I install some software and uninstall it before going to work, can this be monitored by the network administrator?
4. what does it mean that the computer is always connected to abc.xyz.com even at home?!

Answer (score 2):

1. The internet traffic will usually be monitored at the network level, which means your administrator cannot track anything you do at home.
2. Depends how your system is set up. If you have permission you can set up another user account which doesn't connect to a domain, but don't do this without speaking to your system administrator.
3. Assuming you have an install of your OS rather than connecting to a virtual image pool the System Administrator would only see what you have installed by looking at your download history, system logs or remote/physically look at the machine for whats installed.

Obviously this depends on the setup you have, but the above will likely be the case.